# RHQ agent not connecting to RHQServer

Tags: jboss, jbossfuse, apache-servicemix, rhq

I am trying to configure RHQ server to monitor Apache ServiceMix 5.2 . I have installed RHQ Server and now trying to install RHQ agent on same machine which will monitor servicemix running on same machine.

I have tried giving server address as 127.0.0.1 ,my actual IP etc but still I am getting same error every time I start agent.

`2017-05-17 09:25:24,857 ERROR [RHQ Server Polling Thread] (enterprise.communications.command.client.JBossRemotingRemoteCommunicator)- {JBossRemotingRemoteCommunicator.init-callback-failed}The initialize callback has failed. It will be tried again. Cause: org.rhq.enterprise.communications.util.NotProcessedException:null. Cause: org.rhq.enterprise.communications.util.NotProcessedException
2017-05-17 09:15:30,314 WARN  [InventoryManager.discovery-1] (rhq.core.pc.inventory.AutoDiscoveryExecutor)- Exception caught while executing server discovery scan.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The sender object is currently not sending commands now. Command not sent: [Command: type=[remotepojo]; cmd-in-response=[false]; config=[{rhq.timeout=0, rhq.send-throttle=true}]; params=[{invocation=NameBasedInvocation[mergeInventoryReport], targetInterfaceName=org.rhq.core.clientapi.server.discovery.DiscoveryServerService}]]
    at org.rhq.enterprise.communications.command.client.ClientCommandSender.sendSynch(ClientCommandSender.java:623)
    at org.rhq.enterprise.communications.command.client.ClientRemotePojoFactory$RemotePojoProxyHandler.invoke(ClientRemotePojoFactory.java:418)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy4.mergeInventoryReport(Unknown Source)
    at org.rhq.core.pc.inventory.InventoryManager.handleReport(InventoryManager.java:1267)
    at org.rhq.core.pc.inventory.AutoDiscoveryExecutor.call(AutoDiscoveryExecutor.java:121)
    at org.rhq.core.pc.inventory.AutoDiscoveryExecutor.run(AutoDiscoveryExecutor.java:83)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:304)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)`

could anyone please advice?

Comment: Seems like the agent is not configured properly, can you try to reinstall it with the `--cleanconfig` flag?

Comment: tried doing cleanconf but no luck